# Creating a endpoint to return a list of objects from a database using Spring

Tags: java, spring, endpoint

I have a database and I want to use a endpoint to get the data. But I want to filter the data so that only certain values are returned. What I want is to call the endpoint and then get the data that I wanted out of it. I have made two methods one for calling all the data and another for calling only 1 record in the database. they both working good, but I want to now get multiple records from the database. This is what I have so far:

```
 //This get every record
 @RequestMapping(
        value = API_PREFIX_1_0 + ENDPOINT_coupon + "/getCoupon",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Collection<Coupon> couponGetAll()
{
    return couponService.getAll();
}

//this get only one record based on the ID of the table
@RequestMapping(
        value = API_PREFIX_1_0 + ENDPOINT_coupon + "/{id}", 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Coupon couponGetById(@PathVariable(value = "id") final long id) {
    return couponService.getById(id);
}
```

What I want to do is use an array or a list of id to get the data from the server.
Thank you for any help with this

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you want to find the items by any query or via a set of ids or something other?

Comment: Yes like a set of ids and send them to get only the items with matching ids

Comment: So what do you want your URL to be? It sounds like something that should be a POST, with a payload giving the list of IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spring CrudRepository already provides a method to find items by a set of ids:

```
Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids)
```

this method should be triggered by your service if you are using a CrudRepository in your persistence layer.
Then you could add a request parameter to your couponGetAll() method where to get the ids and send it to your service.

```
@RequestMapping( value = API_PREFIX_1_0 + ENDPOINT_coupon + "/listOfCoupons", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public Iterable<Coupon> couponGetMine(@RequestParam(name="ids")String ids) { 
Iterable<Long> longIds = convertToLong(ids);
return couponService.getAll(ids); 
}
```

The client side url to call would look something like this:
.../listOfCoupons?ids=2,4,7,3
In the endpoint you extract the numbers out of the string. Maybe there is a nicer solution but this is what is in my mind in this short time.

Convert the id string e.g.:

```
public Iterable<Long> convertToLong(final String ids){
    String[] idArray = ids.split(",");
    List<Long> idsAsLong = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
        idsAsLong.add(Long.parseLong(idArray[i]));
    }
    return idsAsLong;
}
```

Comment: Ok so I went around all my code and added the iterable, but I don't know how to call it using the endpoint.

Comment: @RequestMapping(
      value = API_PREFIX_1_0 + ENDPOINT_coupon + "/listOfCoupons",
      method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Coupon> couponGetMine(Iterable<Long> id)
    {
     return couponService.getAll(id);
    }

Comment: @MNM just edited the answer. hopefully it will help you

Comment: The only problem I am having is that I cannot convert the String into a Utterable<Long> any ideas on that?

Comment: That works perfectly thank you so very much I really appreciate it. It took me a while to track down so errors in my database. I really appreciate it again thank you a lot